# Invalid client in aqueduct's db_and_auth/wildfire example

Tags: oauth-2.0, dart, aqueduct

I am new to Aqueduct and I am facing a invalid client error whenever I try to make a request to the `/auth/token` or `/auth/code` route. 
I have already added the OAuth2.0 client and verified the secret is correct.
My request to `/auth/token` looks like this:

```
Future main() async {
  var http2 = new http.Client();
  var clientID = "com.wildfire.mobile";
  var clientSecret = "myspecialsecret ";
  var body = "username=usr&password=pwd&grant_type=password";
  var clientCredentials = new Base64Encoder().convert(
      "$clientID:$clientSecret".codeUnits);
  var response = await
  http.post(
      "http://localhost:8081/auth/token",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Authorization": "Basic $clientCredentials"
      },
      body: body);
```

And when I try logging in in `/auth/code` with a username in the _user database the server throws a `400:invalid_client`

Comment: A couple of things to check: is your configuration file pointing at the right database? Did you add the client ID and secret via the aqueduct auth CLI? Also, there's a Slack channel for Aqueduct here: http://aqueductsignup.herokuapp.com

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed a misconfiguration issue. After deleting all my databases, I added a database.yaml file, which I thought was the same as the config.yaml but apparently is not.
The database.yaml looks like this:

```
 username: adan
 password: pass
 host: localhost
 port: 5432
 databaseName: wildfire_db
```

while the config.yaml looks like this:

```
database:
 username: adan
 password: pass
 host: localhost
 port: 5432
 databaseName: wildfire_db
```

I also ran the `aqueduct auth` and `aqueduct db` commands without the --connect flag, i.e. using the config files.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. For clarification, config.yaml is the default name of the config file for your application. It might contain a zero, one or more database credentials, and they might be top-level, nested, etc. CLI commands that connect to a database use the --connect option to provide database credentials. As a convenience, those credentials can be placed in a database.yaml file to avoid having to type them at the CLI. The CLI won't understand the specifics of your application's configuration file, though.